# PDF Renderer Causing Divide By Zero

Tags: java, pdf, printing, awt

I am attempting to **print a PDF document using the java.awt.print package**.  I do so by creating a **Printable** object which does a brief conversion of the file (a technique which was derived from a different topic some time ago).

```
private static void printDocument(File finalFile, PrintService printer, String name) throws PrinterException {

    System.out.println(String.format("Starting %s document", name));

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(finalFile);
        byte[] pdfContent = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
        fileInputStream.read(pdfContent, 0, fileInputStream.available());
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdfContent);
        final PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);

        //Create Printable object in preparation for printing
        Printable printable = new Printable() {

            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

                int pagenum = pageIndex + 1;
                if ((pagenum >= 1) && (pagenum <= pdfFile.getNumPages())) {

                    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                    PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(pagenum);

                    Rectangle imageArea = new Rectangle((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int) pageFormat.getImageableY(),
                            (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth(), (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight());

                    graphics2D.translate(0, 0);
                    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(page, graphics2D, imageArea, null, null);

                    try {
                        page.waitForFinish();
                        pdfRenderer.run();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new PrinterException("Oh noes!");
                    }
                    return PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
                else {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
            }
        };

        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        printJob.setPrintService(printer);

        PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(printable, pageFormat, pdfFile.getNumPages());
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);


        PrintRequestAttributeSet pset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printJob.setJobName(finalFile.getName() +
                "|" + String.valueOf(1) + 
                "|" + ("T"));

        printJob.print(pset);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new PrinterException();
    }
    finally {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Finished %s document", name));
}
```

Certain **specific cases** of PDF files **do not respond well** to this conversion process, failing on the *pdfRenderer.run();* line with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.sun.pdfview.pattern.PatternType1$Type1PaintContext.getRaster(PatternType1.java:354)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.AlphaPaintPipe.renderPathTile(AlphaPaintPipe.java:106)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DuctusShapeRenderer.renderTiles(DuctusShapeRenderer.java:147)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DuctusShapeRenderer.renderPath(DuctusShapeRenderer.java:100)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DuctusShapeRenderer.fill(DuctusShapeRenderer.java:50)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.fill(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:146)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.fill(ValidatePipe.java:142)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fill(SunGraphics2D.java:2376)
    at sun.print.ProxyGraphics2D.fill(ProxyGraphics2D.java:1381)
    at com.sun.pdfview.pattern.PatternType1$TilingPatternPaint.fill(PatternType1.java:278)
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.fill(PDFRenderer.java:261)
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFShapeCmd.execute(PDFShapeCmd.java:77)
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.iterate(PDFRenderer.java:570)
    at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:101)
    at **MYFILEHERE**
```

This causes the file to fail halfway through, and results literally (and somewhat humorously) in a file that only prints halfway, stopping even across the center of lines of text.

**What is the cause of this error?**  It happens at such a low-level within the rendering process, dealing with individual shape manipulation, that I have to believe that it is beyond my control to deal with.  **Is there a way** that I can allow my process to **bypass the corrupt data** that it may be struggling with and continue to render the documents in full?

Comment: What happens here? `PatternType1.java:278` and `PDFRenderer.java:261`

Comment: Suggestion for getting more data: Catch the exception in your code. From the catch block, dump the contents of your buffer to a disk file, and open it in a pdf-reading program. Also, are you sure you are always reading the whole input file?

Comment: @Brian I don't think I can know.  That is com.sun code.

Comment: It's hard to say. It's likely somewhere in your code, but you didn't show us the lines in your code that the stack exception would have shown.

Comment: @Brian Wow, actually, you're right!  PDFRenderer is not from core Sun's Java packages, but rather was taken from a project here: https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/com/sun/pdfview?rev=140 .  That changes everything!  Thank you.

Comment: @Brian It may have been silly in the end, but you deserve credit for helping me with this one.  Feel free to write up an answer directing me to the link I just found.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can post your own answer once you figured out the solution. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the code that was being executed **was not part of Sun's Java's official code**, as suggested by the com.sun package name, but rather a **separate project** located [here](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/).  The code is **open source**, allowing me to check it out, modify [this](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/com/sun/pdfview/pattern/PatternType1.java?rev=140) file, and build myself a new jar all easily.  I will also attempt to contribute my fix to the project if possible.

The fix was simply to add a check to prevent the aforementioned Divide-by-zero error.

Original code:

```
xloc %= useXStep;
yloc %= useYStep;
```

Fixed code:

```
if (xstep != 0)
    xloc %= useXStep;
if (ystep != 0)
    yloc %= useYStep;
```